# Which research groups use stochastic processes and/or stochastic differential equations in computer graphics/vision?

Tags: stochastic-processes, computer-science, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, research

Some research groups use stochastic differential equations for mathematical image processing. Which research groups do use stochastic processes in general and/or stochastic differential equations in the field of computer graphics/vision?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples I like, not of groups but of a few specific works in some areas. For most cases, it's a lot more common to see non-SDE stochastics (e.g. machine learning using stochastics) than, say, explicit simulation of continuous spacetime processes.

**Image Super-resolution**
In *Random Walk Models from Geometry-driven Image Super-Resolution*, Fablet et al model the image's level lines using 2D Orstein-Uhlenbeck processes and simulate them to get the high-res image. Also see works like *Stochastic super-resolution image reconstruction*, Tiana and Mab.

**Non-Linear Filtering**
Check out the works on shape analysis and geometric flows by Unal et al (*Feature-Preserving Flows: a Stochastic Differential Equation's View* and *Stochastic Differential Equations and Geometric flows*). Pretty interesting from a theory point of view.

**Graphics**
Using stochastics for noise in graphics is pretty common (e.g. flow noise), but for SDEs specifically there are papers like *Langevin Particle: A Self-Adaptive Lagrangian Primitive for Flow Simulation Enhancement* by Chen et al and *Stochastic Modeling of Immersed Rigid-body Dynamics* by Xie and Miyata.

**Stochastic Motion Textures**
See *Animating Pictures with Stochastic Motion Textures* by Chuang et al. (Check out their videos of animated still images.)

**Image Segmentation**
In *Stochastic Mean Curvature Motion in Computer Vision: Stochastic Active Contours*, Juan et al stochastically evolve contours to segment images.

**Tracking**
On the more vision side, see *Learning to track the visual motion of contours* by Blake et al, which uses SDEs, and its kin.